# How to do lazy evaluation on a reference to an interface (trying with bind)?

Tags: c++, binding, c++11

I can get `std::bind` to work fine with an instance, but I can't get it to work with a reference to an interface (pure virtual class).

I need this functionality for a lazy evaluation on an interface (which will refer to a concrete instance by run-time).

**COMPILE ERROR**

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:56:0,
                 from junk.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/tuple: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Head_base<0ul, Integer, false>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/tuple:215:12:   required from ‘struct std::_Tuple_impl<0ul, Integer>’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/tuple:374:11:   required from ‘class std::tuple<Integer>’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1148:29:   required from ‘struct std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<int (Integer::*)()const>(Integer)>’
junk.cpp:24:42:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/tuple:166:13: error: cannot declare field ‘std::_Head_base<0ul, Integer, false>::_M_head_impl’ to be of abstract type ‘Integer’
junk.cpp:4:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Integer’:
junk.cpp:6:14: note:    virtual int Integer::getInt() const
make: *** [junk] Error 1
```

Is there a way to get this to work with `std::bind`?  If not, is there something in boost?

**CODE**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Integer
{
    virtual int getInt() const = 0;
};

struct IntImpl : public Integer
{
    virtual int getInt() const { return 42; }
};

int
main( int argv, char* argc[] )
{
    // works fine
    IntImpl  x;
    auto f = std::bind( &Integer::getInt, x );
    std::cerr << f() << std::endl;

    // need an interface because I won't know if concrete class will be x
    // or something else until run-time, but y will refer to that instance
    Integer& y = x; 
    // next line won't compile
    auto g = std::bind( &Integer::getInt, y );
    std::cerr << g() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @K-ballo added it to OP - I think bind is trying to make a copy

Comment: kfmfe04: Yes, `bind` copies its arguments. There is `std::[c]ref` to pass by reference but I'm guessing that won't be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
auto g = std::bind( &Integer::getInt, &y );
```

(add the address-of operator before `y`)

Comment: +1 perfecto! btw, when should I use address and when shouldn't I?

Comment: Note there is also `std::[c]ref` when _pass by reference_ is intended

Comment: @kfmfe04: `std::bind` creates a copy of its arguments, and since `Integer` is abstract, it cannot create a copy. as K-ballo correctly pointed out, you can also use the `std::ref`/`cref` wrapper instead

Comment: @K-ballo +1 - tried that and works fine (actually, it makes more sense  to me than passing the address - not sure why Andy's answer works)

Comment: @kfmfe04: it works for the reason I explained, `std::bind` creates a copy of its arguments: it can create a brand new copy of a *pointer* to an `Integer`, but it cannot create a brand new copy of an `Integer` (because it is abstract)

Comment: got it - it wasn't obvious to me before that bind is smart enough to work with both pointers and references - makes perfect sense now

Comment: @kfmfe04: also, being a *member* function, in theory its first argument is expected to be a pointer (which becomes the `this` pointer), so it does make more sense passing an address IMO. of course you have to take care of object lifetime then, but you can even pass in a `shared_ptr` if you wish to